# Get module namespace of already-loaded script?

Tags: python

How can I get the module object/namespace for an already-loaded script datablock, given only the name/ID/path of the text datablock?

`.as_module()` doesn't do this, because  `D.texts[0].as_module() is D.texts[0].as_module() == False`— `as_module()` returns a new object and namespace, so it can't be used to alter or unregister the already-imported definitions. It also doesn't set `__file__` correctly.

---

Basically, I'm looking for something like `addon_utils.modules()`, except with no fake modules, and if it also included all user scripts from which a type has been registered.

Answer (score 0):

**Method returns a module like object**

Not exactly sure of what you are asking here, the as module method returns a module like object using the code of the datablock.

```
>>> foo = D.texts['Text'].as_module()

>>> foo
<module 'Text'>

>>> foo.__name__
'Text'

>>> D.texts['Text'].as_module().__name__ == D.texts['Text'].as_module().__name__
True
```

Can see no reason to expect that

```
D.texts[0].as_module() is D.texts[0].as_module()
```

or that `__file__` is set.

Related.

[How to import text data blocks as modules using the 'from/import' statement?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212741/how-to-import-text-data-blocks-as-modules-using-the-from-import-statement/212748#212748)

Comment: Currently, I'm assigning `globals()` to `bpy.ModuleName.__dict__` from inside each module/script, so I can call `bpy.ModuleName.unregister()` later. The idea is to be able to get the original namespace for arbitrary modules without requiring the modules to register themselves in that way. `as_module()` doesn't work because it [just creates a new module with `exec`](https://developer.blender.org/rB98876). I would expect there to be some way to get `as_module() is as_module()` because modules are usually singletons shared across multiple import statements, and the types are clearly kept around.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for something like `addon_utils.modules()`, except with no fake modules, and if it also included all user scripts that had been run— Although, how such arbitrary and potentially conflicting data would be best sorted and discarded may be messy.

Comment: Have you investigated the source of `addon_utills.modules()` ??

Comment: also IMO both methods in answer link show are examples re  how to do  this too. The `as_module()` method returns a new module like object using the code in the texblock How to make your own module like object instead is well covered on stackoverlow.

Comment: Unfortunately, while those methods are interesting, I believe they still require cooperation from either the original script's scope or the importing scope? I can already do that; what I'd like is to get the namespace of any arbitrary previously-run script when knowing nothing but its name, and without requiring it to have been loaded a certain way. Making a new module(-like) object is a different question IMO; you can't unregister or monkey-patch the original script if you just make a new object.