# How to import script from Text editor to Python Console?

Tags: python, scripting

### Problem description

---

I've got a simple script in Text Editor

[image]

And want to get the function defined in it be able to execute from Python Console.
 Old Blender Cookie tutorial says that all I have to do is write in console:

```
>>> from rename import BatchRename
>>> BatchRename('Monkey')
```

But I've got a Traceback message
[image]

I looked through a lot of artitcles but only [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/how-to-run-a-python-script-external-to-blender-to-run-bpy-commands-in-blendersp/51159#51159) was helpfull.
And the only way I could refer to this script from console and execute the BatchRename function was

```
>>> filepath = bpy.path.abspath("//rename.py")
>>> exec(compile(open(filepath).read(), filepath, 'exec'))
```

### Questions

---

Why the first script doesn't work?
What is the best working method to refer to Script from the Text Editor From Python Console?

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212748/53513) answer your question?

Comment: you need to install the `BatchRename` module. you can install it with [`pip package manager`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)). but i don't know what the corresponding package name is that includes the module batchrename. let me know what it is and i can continue teach how to run your script.

Comment: I posted a question on ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421766/issue-error-installing-package-rename-in-python-3-10-2

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer to the scripting side of your question, but if you're looking to batch rename things in your file, there already exists a function for that.

It's called Batch Rename and it can be found in the Edit Menu. You can also call it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

[image]

It has several features to allow you to fine tweak the object names. You can also set it to discriminately rename only objects or only bones, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate that, but I've already known about this feature. The main idia here is to make Python Console refer to functions from text editor =)