# How can I run/execute a text block from within Python with the new temp context override syntax of Blender 4.0?

Tags: python

In Blender versions before 4.0, I would execute text blocks with the following Python code.

```
# Retrieve the text file
rig_file = bpy.data.texts["hello.py"]
rig_text = rig_file.as_string()

# Modify text string as needed here ...

# Execute the script
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
ctx['edit_text'] = rig_file
bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
```

This worked flawlessly in 3.6. Now in 4.0, [passing in context overrides has been depricated in favor of Context.temp_override.](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/deprecationwarning-passing-in-context-overrides-is-deprecated-in-favor-of-context-temp-override/27870)

How would I execute this code in 4.0 and beyond? I know it would have to be in the syntax of the temp_override, but what do I pass in to the with block to make this work?

```
# [4.0] Execute the script
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
ctx['edit_text'] = rig_file
with bpy.context.temp_override(): # What do I pass in?
     bpy.ops.text.run_script() # Is this still correct in 4.0?
```

Edit: For convenience I'll post the documentation on text operators: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.text.html
You will notice that `run_script()` doesn't take in anything anymore, and that it is described as running the 'active script'. The question is, how do I set my text file as the active script to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. We pass in edit_text.

So our **complete** code block now is:

```
# Retrieve the text file
rig_file = bpy.data.texts["hello.py"]
rig_text = rig_file.as_string()

# Modify text string as needed here ...

# [4.0] Execute the script
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
ctx['edit_text'] = rig_file
with bpy.context.temp_override(edit_text=rig_file):
    bpy.ops.text.run_script()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For reference I added it to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides

Comment: @Gorgious That is amazing documentation. Thank you for your hard work.

Answer (score 2):

There's also an alternative operator-less way to run a text block - [`as_module()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Text.html#bpy.types.Text.as_module)

```py
>>> with C.temp_override(edit_text = D.texts['A']):
...     bpy.ops.text.run_script()
...     
a
{'FINISHED'}

>>> D.texts['A'].as_module()
a
<module 'A' from 'A'>
```

The advantage of that is that you can call functions within that module:

```py
>>> module_A = D.texts['A'].as_module()
a

>>> module_A.multiply_by_3(
multiply_by_3(number_to_multiply)
>>> module_A.multiply_by_3(6)
18
```

To clarify, that's the contents of the *"A"* Text Block:

```py
print("a")

def multiply_by_3(number_to_multiply):
    return number_to_multiply*3
```

[How to import text data blocks as modules using the 'from/import' statement?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/212741/60486)